# Applying ifelse function to transform entire column in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, grepl

I have a data frame such as this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 y = c(-1, -2, 3, 1))
```

And I want to multiply the values of `df$y` by -1 if the value of `A` is less than 0, as is the case here. So instead of being `(-1, -2, 3, 1)`, it becomes `(1, 2, -3, -1)`.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
df$y <- ifelse(df[df$x == "A", 2] < 0, df$y*-1, df$y)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem description doesn't match the posted expected output. In that output you multiply the *entire* column `y` by `-1`, without considering the value of column `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do:

```
df$y <- ifelse(df$x == "A" & df$y < 0, df$y * -1, df$y)
```

If you want to multiply all, then something like:

```
df$y <- if (any(df$x == "A" & df$y < 0)) df$y * -1 else df$y
```

Comment: This only results in flipping the value of `df$y` when `df$x="A"`, but I want to flip all  `df$y` values when `df$x="A"`.